# TVS selection guidance to protect against overvoltage on AC line

Tags: ac, dc, tvs, transformerless, mov

I used this [link](http://powersupply33.com/transformerless-power-supply-from-220v-with-lm2575.html) to generate a 5VDC (1A) from the 220Vac power source, the circuit itself works perfectly fine but I want to make sure that the overvoltage on the AC line won't damage my board.

I searched the web and noticed that for protecting my board against the overvoltage on the AC line I should use the MOV device connected between the Line and Neutral.

In addition I noticed that there is a device called bi-directional TVS diode used to protect the device from the voltage spikes and it connects to the AC line in parallel just like the MOV.

The problem is that I'm not familiar with the TVS devices and I don't know which TVS diode is suitable for my application.

Please give me some suggestion for the suitable bi-directional TVS diode.
I also attached the transformer-less power supply design for reference.
[image]

Comment: I would personally be much more worried about galvanic isolation

Comment: @PlasmaHH Could you please elaborate more on the "Galvanic isolation" term?

Comment: not as good as google can

Comment: @PlasmaHH I searched the web, that is not a problem for my application

Comment: Why don't you ask the guy who designed it what to use? After all, the design link you supplied shows a schematic with very little information about the transistors and resistor power levels. Knowing what to protect tells you how to protect it. I also agree with @PlasmaHH and you might get more help if you state what the target load is.

Comment: You need impedance in series in order to make the TVS useful. No common mode choke on the input?

Comment: @Andyaka unfortunately the design space that i have is very limited and i can't use the common mode choke (as far as i know they need a lot of space to fit in), the target load is just a simple 8 bit micro controller and a temperature sensor that consume less than 100mA

Comment: Please justify how using an un-isolated (no transformer) supply is safe in your target application. I did not mention a common mode choke BTW and without a fuller parts list for the components I can't help.

Comment: @Andyaka T1 is BC547, T2 is IRF730, let me know if you need the name of any other components

Comment: @Andyaka unfortunately i can't attach more that 2 link to the original post, use this [link](http://www.picbasic.co.uk/forum/showthread.php?t=12249) for more information about the schematic

Comment: R1 power rating and D1 power ratings are my main concern. Once these are addressed I would look to change T2 to a higher voltage rated device. How much over-voltage are you trying to protect against?

Comment: The circuit in itself is a good idea (if no galvanic isolation is required, indeed). However, more than overvoltages on mains, what is likely to destroy it is the fact that you repetitively overdrive the gate voltage of T2. It seems to go as high as the ~45V you provide as input of the LM2575. Also, I think you are really pushing the limits of the LM2575 input voltage (unless you use the HV version).

Comment: @dim good call on the over-voltage on the gate of T2 - another zener diode would help here.

Comment: By the way, I **love** designing circuits myself, but when it comes to power supplies, I tend to do "how much money do I have to spend to buy something that has the experience of someone who specializes in power supply built in". In your case, the LM2575HV (which you **must** use, the normal LM2575 will fail as @dim [said](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266674/protect-my-circuit-from-overvoltage-on-ac-line#comment598775_266674)) costs about USD5.00 – for little more than that price, you can get a *complete*, appropriate-quality, USB power supply which already has protection.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for your suggestion.
I'll replace the LM2575 with the LM2575HV.

Comment: @MehdiHafezi **NO!!!!** *Read my answer.* Don't use this circuit at all. It is like you ask something, and then don't care about what the answers are.

Comment: @Andyaka The circuit appears "all over" - the guy wo designed it is lost in the mists of time - and probably dies of electrocution.

Comment: If you DO use this cct you MUST put a zener from T2 g-s to limit Vgate to < Vgs max for the FET. At present the 40V or so peak SHOULD destroy it. | The circuit is very clever and "quite fun" **BUT** I would not touch it with a very very very long barge pole in the real world. It may run forever OK, but if the psu and all connected equipment erupted in a ball of flame at any time at all I'd be in no way surprised. You are fighting dark magic here - even more so than with a series capacitor supply and utter catastrophe is only a most minor failure away.  If that.

Comment: R1 MUST be rated for peak mains voltage. Most R's are not. That's why there are 2 x R4 but they forgot R1. Be FULLY aware that any point on this cct must be considered to always be at full mains potential. ALWAYS.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks for the information, the circuit is online for at least 2 month with no problem (if the load goes higher than 500mA the temperature of the R3 will rise up so i changed the R3 to 1Ohm and every thing is now fine).
the hole board is in the plastic box and no one to going to touch it.
I'll put the proper zener diode between the gate and source of the T2 for more protection as well as using two 20K resistor instead of one for R1.

Comment: @MehdiHafezi Yes. As I said " It **may** run forever OK". The output 5V and all things connected must be regarded as being are at mains voltage. | What is it powering? What is the maximum output current?

Comment: Manufacturers specify protection device for use across various AC mains voltages. Ones suitable for your purpose should be described as such in a spec sheet. Adding a small series resistor in the main lead on the main-side of them will help their survival and effectiveness. Higher power ratings = more effectiveness and more cost. I'd consider a zener across C1 and a series fast blow fuse.T2 may act as such a fuse if the need arose but not dependably. Zener voltage is slightly > Vc1 max. Lowering D1 voltage "would not hurt".

Answer (score 4):

If you care about overvoltage protection, you shouldn't use this kind of circuit. It's **dangerous**.

The most likely part to fail in an overvoltage situation is T2, in which case there's full recitified 220VAC over D1, which will fail, so there's full rectified 220VAC over your 5V output, which will probably make D2 explode, moments before VD1 does the same (hopefully; diodes often fail in a mode that make them short circuits, thus shorting the power line, thus killing the fuse in your house, so lethal risk is limited to a short period of time).

Generally, I fully agree with [PlasmaHH's comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266674/protect-my-circuit-from-overvoltage-on-ac-line#comment598746_266674) that you shouldn't use this at all – there's no galvanic separation from grid to 5V, and that is never a good thing. Components might fail, and then you'd instantly have 220V at your 5V output, killing whatever (or worse: **whoever**) is there.

You won't find this kind of schematic in modern application notes on how to build off-line converters, simply because it

1. lacks protection due to lacking galvanic isolation and hence, cannot be sold as commercial product, very often
2. is not a very effective way of building such a thing, both cost- and power-wise.

To explain: The Left half of your schematic, ie. between your diode bridge VD1 and your buffer capacitor C1 is really just a very simple linear converter, wasting a lot of power.

It is a clutch employed by the designer of the circuit to work around the fact that, due to point 1. above, you typically can't find step down controllers specified for a > 100V input, 5V output range (you can definitely build those without any problem using a lot of existing chips, though it's harder than what the guy who wrote your link did).

For off-grid applications, you'd typically want some controller IC to not control a buck-architecture (the L1/D1 switching thing), but something that, long story short, switches one side of a transformer. That transformer will be the isolating part between your precious life (and not-as-precious board) and grid, and also doesn't waste energy like the T1 and T2 linear voltage controller (and hence, won't get as hot).

In that architecture, you can add overvoltage protection on the primary side very easily (overvoltage -> overcurrent-> fuse blows, for example) without risking the secondary side, because that can just leave out a few cycles until the overvoltage condition has cleared. Also, primary coils of such transformers are far less sensitive to overvoltage than T1/T2 are.

---

**Conclusion**

Don't take random blogs' circuits of the internet when there's grid voltage involved; life is too precious for that.

Manufacturers of ICs like the LM2575 do have websites with both application notes on how to build power supplies, and even more helpful, complete design guides where you essentially just type in "input: 220VAC, output 5V @ 1A", and get a board schematic, including a bill of materials, an analysis of how well everything operates, etc.

These schematics tend to be relatively complete, and include overvoltage protection (within bounds of what is to expect in a typical environment).

Comment: FWIW the input cct is not just a linear converter. When V out of bridge is less than about 40 Vdc C1 can be charged by mains. When Vdc in >= 40V D1 conducts and turns on T1 which clamps gs on T2 and turns off feed to C1. So cct draws power on valleys of Ac mains and typically does so for portion around 35-40V depending how much C1 dips between half cycles. So while power factor is attrocious power efficiency might be OK. However T2 Vgs rises to about Vd1 which should destroy T2.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon hm, true. It *kind of* is a net-synchronous SMPS, but uaaargggh... let's hope the Ugs rises fast enough to put T2 out of misery fast.

Comment: From my comments above on his question: " ... The circuit is very clever and "quite fun" BUT I would not touch it with a very very very long barge pole in the real world. ..." -> :-) :-(. Clever. Lethal. Lifespan uncertain.

Answer (score 0):

This is unsafe, use certified "AC overvoltage switch" that cuts off power automatically when voltage is too high.